# Change content of NavBar in Angular based on ngIf condition

Tags: node.js, angular, web-applications, node-modules

I am a beginner in Angular and Node JS. I am trying a simple navigation bar change based on ngIf condition. However, it doesn't seem to work.

I have already tried it using static member variables.

Also, tried creating a method which changes the value of `isUserAuthenticated` in `navbar.component` and called the methods in `homepage.component` as well as `dashboard.component`.

I have also done `console.log()` and checked the value of `isUserAuthenticated` variable. It is being updated on both the `homepage.component` as well as `dashboard.component`. However, the NavBar always remains the same.

I have changed the value directly in navbar.component and then it works. So, I am wandering why it is not working if I change the value from other components.

navbar.component.html

```
       <div *ngIf="!isUserAuthenticated">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/"> EX FALSE </a>
          </li>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="isUserAuthenticated">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/"> EX TRUE </a>
          </li>
        </div>
```

navbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  isUserAuthenticated = true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  public authenticate() {
    this.isUserAuthenticated = false;
    return  this.isUserAuthenticated;
  }
  public deauthenticate() {
    this.isUserAuthenticated = true;
    return  this.isUserAuthenticated;
  }
}
```

homepage.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavbarComponent } from '../navbar/navbar.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.css']
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log("here");
    this.deauthenticate();


  }

  public deauthenticate()
  {
    const comp2 = new NavbarComponent();
    comp2.deauthenticate();
    console.log(comp2.deauthenticate());
  }
}
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavbarComponent } from '../navbar/navbar.component';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.authenticate();
  }

  public authenticate()
  {
    const comp2 = new NavbarComponent();
    comp2.authenticate();
    console.log(comp2.authenticate());
  }

}
```

I want that `dashboard` component shows "EX TRUE" in NavBar and `homepage` component shows "EX FALSE" in NavBar.

Comment: you should use some service for managing your authentication state and creating new components that are not part of rendered view is why your method calls dont do anything

Comment: this question looks different now do you want to have global state for authentication or just local for each place its displayed?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is working now. I have upvoted your answer and marked as correct. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment you need to create service for authentication [check this for full example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sharing-authentication-state)

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  authenticated$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  public authenticate() {
    this.authenticated$.next(true);
  }

  public deauthenticate() {
    this.authenticated$.next(false);
  }
}
```

you inject it this way to be able to use it in template

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../authentication/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './navbar.component.css' ]
})
export class NavbarComponent {
  constructor(
    public authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
  ) {
  }
}
```

and then in template you can do this

```
Authenticated {{ authenticationService.authenticated$ | async }}

<div *ngIf="(authenticationService.authenticated$ | async) === true">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/">EX TRUE</a>
  </li>
</div>

<div *ngIf="(authenticationService.authenticated$ | async) === false">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/">EX FALSE</a>
  </li>
</div>

<button (click)="authenticationService.authenticate()">Authenticate</button>
<button (click)="authenticationService.deauthenticate()">Deauthenticate</button>
```

Although i would suggest using ngSwitch in this case like this:

```
<div>
  <li class="nav-item" [ngSwitch]="authenticationService.authenticated$ | async">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/" *ngSwitchCase="true">EX TRUE</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="/" *ngSwitchDefault>EX FALSE</a>
  </li>
</div>
```

Also if you want separate state for some parts of your site you can do it like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './homepage.component.css' ],
  // this way you have a separate instance of AuthenticationService here anything that will use this service and is rendered under this component will use a localized version of this service
  providers: [AuthenticationService],
})
export class HomepageComponent {
  constructor(
    public authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
  ) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am almost there. It is working with the NavBar you have provided. Could you please let me know how can I refer `authenticationService.authenticated$` in *ngIf.

For example, I want to do something like below:
```<div *ngIf="!authenticationService.isUserAuthenticated$ | async ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/"> EX FALSE </a>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="authenticationService.isUserAuthenticated$ | async ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/"> EX TRUE </a>
        </div>```

Comment: for ngIf it would be `*ngIf="(authenticationService.authenticated$ | async) === true"` or false in the other case

Comment: Also i have added example with ngSwitch that should be better in this two value case just refresh my answer

Comment: It is working now. Thank you so much. It was really helpful. I will try to learn this kind of basic concepts of Angular.

Comment: I have added some more descriptions into example if anything wasn't clear you can check updated version

Answer (score 1):

That is not how things are designed to work. For this scenario, you need to create a `Service` such as `AuthService` which will be shared across both component.

**AuthEventSvc**

```
export class AuthEventSvc{

   private authEvent = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
   constructor(){}

   emitAuthStatus(state: boolean){
     this.authEvent.next(state);
   }

   authListener(){
     return this.authEvent.asObservable();
   }

}
```

and then emit from **HomeComponent**

```
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authEvent: AuthEventSvc ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authEvent.emitAuthStatus(false);
  }
}
```

and subscribe it in **NavBarComponent**

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  isUserAuthenticated = true;
  authSubscription : Subscription;

  constructor(private authEvent: AuthEventSvc) { }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.authSubscription = this.authEvent.authListener().subscribe(state => {
      this.isUserAuthenticated = state;
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.authSubscription.unsubscribe(); // make sure to unsubscribe
  }

}
```

You should also read about [how change detection works](https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular-33f9ffff6f10) and how `NgZone` is used in Angular to get more clarity as these topics require a long article for explanation. I am just giving you some breadcrumbs to help you understand better :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.
I am new to Angular and NodeJS, so it will really help me understand better with your explanation.

Could you please let me know where to create AuthService. Is it a component?

Comment: @harshpamnani `AuthService` is a service (`component` is different thing). I would highly recommend you to get familiar with basic features of `angular`. Create this service in the same module where you have created all other components. Make sure to put `@Injectable` and all to use it. I once created a git repo https://github.com/shashankvivek/Angular4 while I was exploring `angular`. See if it can helpful to you as well :) Cheers .

Comment: Sure. Thank you so much for the quick reply. I will definitely have a look at the git repo, mark and upvote the answer. Thank you again.

Comment: link is dead...